# Where can I edit apache configuration in Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform

I'm a newbie when it comes to setting up apache2 configuration in GCP. I was tasked to provide HSTS and CSP and eventually add it in either of these files: `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`. Now I search the said files but I cant find it somewhere. Is is possible that I have different files? What file should I add HSTS and CSP configuration in my server?

Comment: If you use a VM, you can configure your VM. If you use a container, you can configure your container. Where are you stuck? On which service?

Comment: I was stuck on which file to edit since I don't have the specific file above. I'm not sure if the apache config is this file on my end /etc/apache2/apache.conf

Comment: What do you use? On which service? What did you install?